# Naming an object dynamically?

Tags: java, reflection

My problem is to name an object dynamically when it is created and the name comes as input from user.

The following is my code in which I can create an object dynamically but I have to name it specifically before like in this case 'obj'

```
private Class ClassName=null;
private Object obj=null;

ClassName=Class.forName(token[2]);
obj=ClassName.newInstance();
```

all I need is to create object as the user specifies its name like if he says object must be named 'x' rather than 'obj'

Comment: Why you are trying to do like this? How it is useful to your user? he won't see any of your code.

Comment: You can't "name" an object dynamically or otherwise since *Objects* don't have names. Only *variables* have names, and these names almost don't exist in compiled code, so this really is a non-question. We need a "sticky" Java FAQ section because this same tired question gets asked over and over and over again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects don't have names. Variables have. But you can't create variables dynamically. If you want to associate objects with names, use a `Map<String, Object>`:

```
Map<String, Object> objectsByName = new HashMap<String, Object>();
...
objectsByName.put("Joe", obj);
...
Object objectNamedJoe = objectsByName.get("Joe");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't rename your variable name cause this is a compile time process, user inputs are runtime